# curly brackets - recursion

Tags: c++, data-structures, curly-brackets

I've read some previous questions about the use of curly brackets, from my understanding it's ok to not use the curly brackets if you have only one line but if you were to use many lines of code you would need to use brackets.

I have an assignment and the instructor does require us to use the brackets for every situation for good habit. He also allows us to research and use sample code.

Now, my question is, I found some sample code that does not use brackets. When i try to add the brackets into the code it makes my output incorrect. 
**Can someone explain to me how to correctly use the curly brackets in multiple lines of code and suggest a recommendation on how i may achieve the results i'm looking for.**

Here is the code when the output is correct:

```
void printStars(int i, int n)
// The calling program invokes this function as follows: printStars(1, n);
// n >= 1
{ 
if(i == n)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) cout << '*'; cout << endl;
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) cout << '*'; cout << endl;
} 
    else
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) cout << '*'; cout << endl;
        printStars(i+1, n); // recursive invocation

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) cout << '*'; cout << endl;
    }
} // printStars

int main() {
    int n;
    int i=0;

        cout << "Enter the number of lines  in the grid: ";
        cin>> n;
        cout << endl;

        printStars(i,n);

    return 0;
}
```

and when i try to "clean it up" looking like this:

```
void printStars(int i, int n)
// The calling program invokes this function as follows: printStars(1, n);
{
    if(i == n)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cout << '*';
            cout << endl;
        }
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cout << '*';
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << '*';
            cout << endl;
        }
        printStars(i+1, n); // recursive invocation

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << '*';
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
} // printStars

int main() {
    int n;
    int i=0;

        cout << "Enter the number of lines  in the grid: ";
        cin>> n;
        cout << endl;

        printStars(i,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remember that a statement ends with a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: yes, am i missing one?

Comment: the compiler does not mind if you put multiple statements on a line. But if you add curly brackets around a single statement, you should not add it to the second statement on the same line.

Comment: ok i see what you saying thanks for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you put too much in the printing loops:

```
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        cout << '*';
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Should be:

```
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Loops without curly braces can only contain a **single** statement. This means the end-of-line print using `cout` is only called when the loops end.

This is the full code using curly braces:

```
void printStars(int i, int n)
// The calling program invokes this function as follows: printStars(1, n);
// n >= 1
{ 
if(i == n)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << endl;
} 
    else
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << endl;

        printStars(i+1, n); // recursive invocation

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
} // printStars

int main() {
    int n;
    int i=0;

        cout << "Enter the number of lines  in the grid: ";
        cin>> n;
        cout << endl;

        printStars(i,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok so the endl has to be outside the loop? it works perfectly by the way thank you!

Comment: Well, if we agree that without curly braces the `for` loop applies to only a single statement, we can understand the second statement (the `cout << endl`) is not part of the loop. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, i'm still new to stack overflow how do i give credit? i don't think i have enough "reputation" to give a vote up

Comment: i got a neg 2 was my question a bad one? i felt like i did research the question prior to asking it...

Comment: Thanks for sending me that link. I will be more informed on how to ask the question correctly.